# Request body could not be parsed

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to get the below error resolved but I could not

Below is the code.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> BVNMatch_Testing(string BVN, string Acc_No, string bank_code, string firstname, string lastname)
{
    var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paystack_SecretKey"];
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.paystack.co/bvn/match"))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {secretKey}");
          
            request.Content = new StringContent("{ \"bvn\": "+ BVN + ",\n      \"account_number\": " + Acc_No + ",\n      \"bank_code\": " + bank_code + ",\n      \"first_name\": " + firstname + ",\n      \"last_name\": " + lastname + "\n  }");

            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            BVNMatch myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BVNMatch>(jsonString);
            return Json(myDeserializedClass);
        }
    }
}
```

The error it keeps bringing when I call the API from the frontend is :

> **Request body could not be parsed. Make sure request body matches specified content-type: application/json**

Am I missing out anything?

Comment: Please never manually construct JSON data, instead use something like [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) to do it for you

Comment: Not much has changed since yesterday. We can repeat the guidance we gave you: Don't create a json payload by doing string concat.

Comment: On which line exactly in the above code do you get that error?

Comment: @rene,  request.Content = new StringContent("{ \"bvn\": "+ BVN + ",\n      \"account_number\": " + Acc_No + ",\n      \"bank_code\": " + bank_code + ",\n      \"first_name\": " + firstname + ",\n      \"last_name\": " + lastname + "\n  }");

Comment: @rene, I am having issues with the construction of the JSOn if you can assist

Answer (score 3):

(would be a mess in comments)
You can use JsonConvert and anonymous types to construct your payload. ie:

```
 var payload = new
{
    bvn = "BVN",
    account_number = "Acc_No",
    bank_code = "bank_code",
    first_name = "firstname",
    last_name = "lastname"
};

request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
```

(You would use actual values).
Or better yet:

```
var postdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    sw.Write(postData);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this but it keeps highlighting the line request.Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);  The error is CANNOT IMPLICITLY CONVERT TYPE STRING TO SYSTEM.NET.HTTP.HTTPCONTENT

Comment: @mantics `request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);`

Comment: See using(...).

Comment: Hello, I am going with the former method but below is what the json generates.  "{\r\n  \"BVN\": \"123456789\",\r\n  \"account_number\": \"0689688574\",\r\n  \"bank_code\": \"052\",\r\n  \"first_name\": \"myname\",\r\n  \"last_name\": \"mysurname\"\r\n}"  and the Endpoint expects it to be in this format  "{ \"bvn\": \"123456789\",\n      \"account_number\": \"0689688574\",\n      \"bank_code\": \"052\",\n      \"first_name\": \"myname\",\n      \"last_name\": \"mysurname\"\n  }"

Comment: So with the above, it returns that the BVN is required

Comment: @mantics Why would you go with the former method. I gave you the method that you should use.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the main problem is that you're manually concatenating JSON data, which is *quite* bad, as it is very error prone (as you're figuring out right now).

The Actual problem in your question is that your concatenating your JSON wrong. Printing it out to the console results in this:

```
{ "bvn": BVN,
      "account_number": Acc_No,
      "bank_code": bank_code,
      "first_name": first_name,
      "last_name": lastname
  }
```

Which is not valid JSON. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gMuoEY) is my code that's resulting in this. Valid JSON needs to have a quote around anything that isn't an integer, a boolean or an object.

You *could* (but shouldn't) fix it by adding an escaped `"` before all of your variables. Like `\"bvn\": \"" + BVN + "\",\n"`, but see how that's really hard to read? A little better is `$"\"bvn\": \"{BVN}\""` but that's still not good. Instead, use the built in [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) (if you're using .NET Core 3.1 or newer) or [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (if you're using .NET Framework). Here is how you would do it with Newtonsoft.Json (as your question is tagged with the .NET Framework ASP.NET):

```cs
public class MatchPayload
{
    [JsonProperty("bvn")]
    public string Bvn {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("account_number")]
    public string AccountNumber {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("bank_code")]
    public string BankCode {get; set;}    

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> BVNMatch_Testing([FromBody] MatchPayload payload)
{
    var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paystack_SecretKey"];
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.paystack.co/bvn/match"))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {secretKey}");
          
            // See how easier and cleaner this is?
            request.Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            BVNMatch myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BVNMatch>(jsonString);
            return Json(myDeserializedClass);
        }
    }
}
```